# Scraping a lot of pages with multiple machines (with different IPs)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have to scrape information from several web pages and use BeautifulSoup + requests + threading. I create many workers, each one grabs a URL from the queue, downloads it, scrapes data from HTML and puts the result to the result list. [This](http://pastie.org/10466042) is my code, I thought it was too long to just paste it here.

But I ran into following problem - this site probalby limits the quantity of requests from one IP per minute, so scraping becomes not as fast as it could be. But a have a server that has a different IP, so I thought I could make use of it.

I thought of creating a script for the server that would listen to some port (with sockets) and accept URLs, process them, and then send the result back to my main machine.

But I'm not sure if there is no ready-made solution, the problem seems common to me. If there is, what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the web servers make use use of `rate limiting` to save resources and keep themselves from `DoS` attacks; its a common security measure.

Now looking into your problem these are the things you could do.

1. Put some sleep in between different different requests (it will
   bring down the request per second count; and server may not treat
   your code as robot)
2. If you are using an internet connection on your home computer and it is not using any static IP address then you may try rebooting your router every time your request gets denied using simple telnet interface to the router.
3. If you are using cloud server/VPS you can buy multiple IP address and keep switching your requests through different network interfaces it can also help you lower down the request per second.

You will need to check through the real cause of denial from the server you are pulling webpages from; it is very general topic to write any definitive answer; here are certain things you can do to find out what is causing your requests to be denied and choose one of the aforementioned method to fix the problem.

1. Decrease the requests per second count and see how web server is performing.
2. Set the request headers of HTTP to simulate a web-browser and see if its blocking or not.
3. Bandwidth of your internet connection/ Network connection limit of your machine could also be problem; use netstat to monitor number of active connection before and after your requests are being blocked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already do your suggestion №1, and unfortunately, I have a static IP adress, so I will stick with the third option.